# Windows 10 v 1709 breaks out of hibernate; is it "DmClientOnScenarioDownload"?

Tags: hibernate

I have three Dell computers that are breaking out of hibernate sporadically.  The current "superuser" resolutions have been tried and failed.  I searched for an Event Viewer entry for 11/11/2017 (04:18:xx) and then looked at Task Scheduler.  I expanded the task scheduler explorer and spent 5 minutes looking for a time stamp of 11/11/2017 (04:18/xx). The only entry was in this path:

Task Scheduler > Microsoft > Windows > Feedback > Siuf > DmClientOnScenarioDownload

It was Status: Ready. and I am testing it Status: Disabled.

Question: Is that source a likely cause or just an effect of hibernate breaking?